# Java: Saving Map.keySet() into ArrayList throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, hashmap, stack-overflow

I'm programming an elevator simulation. If I run the simulation only a few times (approx: 1-50 times), the StackOverflowError usually doesn't occur. However, I have to run the simulation approx. 1000 times.

I have different classes. The error occurs in class "n_AlgorithmMain" when the following is executed:
`waitingPassengerId = new ArrayList<>(waitingPassengerMap.keySet());`. "WaitingPassengerId" is created like:
`private List<Integer>  waitingPassengerId;`.

The whole function is:

```
protected LinkedListMultimap<Integer, Integer> filledInsidePassengerMap(LinkedListMultimap<Integer,Integer> waitingPassengerMap, int currentFloor){

    servedWaitingPassengerId = new ArrayList<>();

    waitingPassengerId = new ArrayList<>(waitingPassengerMap.keySet());

    for(int i = 0; i < waitingPassengerId.size() ; i++){
        waitingPassengerValues = waitingPassengerMap.get(waitingPassengerId.get(i));
        passengerStartFloor = fetchPassengerStartFloor(waitingPassengerValues);
        if(passengerStartFloor == currentFloor){
            for(int j = 0; j < waitingPassengerValues.size(); j++){
                insidePassengerMap.put(waitingPassengerId.get(i), waitingPassengerValues.get(j));
            }
            servedWaitingPassengerId.add(waitingPassengerId.get(i)); 
        }
    }
    waitingPassengerMap = adjustedMap(waitingPassengerMap, servedWaitingPassengerId);
    return insidePassengerMap;
}
```

I'm not sure but maybe the problem is triggered by the following code in class "n_AlgorithmStandard", because the above function is called from "n_AlgorithmStandard":
 `insidePassengerMap = filledInsidePassengerMap(standardWaitingPassengerMap, standardCurrentFloor);`.

I think that it would also be triggered at the following line, which is currently not reached:
`finishedPassengerMap = filledFinishedPassengerMap(insidePassengerMap, standardCurrentFloor);`.

These maps were initialized as follows:

`private LinkedListMultimap<Integer, Integer> insidePassengerMap = LinkedListMultimap.create();`
and
`private LinkedListMultimap<Integer, Integer> finishedPassengerMap = LinkedListMultimap.create();`.

The whole function in "n_AlgorithmStandard" looks like these:

```
private void processOneFloor() {

    standardWaitingPassengerMap = filledWaitingPassengerMap(timeMap, standardCurrentFloor, isRfid, emptyRandomAmountList); 
    currentSumRandomAmount = getSumRandomAmount();

    insidePassengerMap = filledInsidePassengerMap(standardWaitingPassengerMap, standardCurrentFloor);
    finishedPassengerMap = filledFinishedPassengerMap(insidePassengerMap, standardCurrentFloor);

    moveElevator();

    if (currentSumRandomAmount < passengerAmountTotal) {
        processOneFloor();
    } else if (currentSumRandomAmount == passengerAmountTotal){
        processRemainingPassengers(standardWaitingPassengerMap, insidePassengerMap);
        remainingPassengersAmountStandard = getRemainingPassengersAmount();

        for (int i = 0; i < remainingPassengersAmountStandard; i++){
            processOneFloor();
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:629)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
at com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap$DistinctKeyIterator.next(LinkedListMultimap.java:448)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at n_AlgorithmMain.filledInsidePassengerMap(n_AlgorithmMain.java:309)
at n_AlgorithmStandard.processOneFloor(n_AlgorithmStandard.java:142)
```

The last line occurs like 100 times in the Stacktrace.

Comment: The topmost line in a StackOverflowError is meaningless. The putVal call just happened to be the one at which the JVM said enough is enough. The real error stems from the repeating lines, i.e. the processOneFloor method.

Comment: you algorithm is recursive as you probably know, but as I'm guessing by the variable name currentSumRandomAmount you are also playing a bit with random values. Recursion and random value don't usually go well together since you may never reach the base case step of your recursion, so I just advice to double check the logic of your entire program.

Comment: processOneFloor method is recursive, debug the recursion call to figure things out

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there an approach to solve the "problem" with the random values? @GionJh

Comment: you just have to make sure the the base case or one of the base cases is always reached, If I were you I would give myself a bit of a refresher on recursion and try again :)

Comment: There are plenty of resources online, this could be a start: http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html

Comment: @Arun So you mean i should clear the recursion function "processOneFloor"? I don't know how, because the recursion is needed there.

Comment: @GionJh Thanks, I'm new with recursion, so I clearly have to look at the link :)

Comment: Every call to processOneFloor method will only terminate 
if(currentSumRandomAmount > passengerAmountTotal)
So, this marks your base case for termination. And since you received StackOverflowError that means your method getSumRandomAmount() never returns a number > passengerAmountTotal. So, please check the method getSumRandomAmount.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I solved the problem.